# how to update data which get it from combobox?

Tags: php, mysql, combobox, updates

pls help me

I need your help..

In my web site, I let the employee to chose the department name that he wants from comboBox using this code

```
$dept_id = $_SESSION['dept_id'];
    $from= "SELECT d.dept_id, d.name FROM department d LEFT JOIN employee e ON d.dept_id = e.dept_id WHERE emp_id = '$emp_id' ";
    $result_form = mysql_query($from);
    //$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result_form); // get 1st result row

    $dept_from = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_form);
$dept_name = $dept_from['name'];
    //$row=mysql_fetch_array($result_form);
    //echo    $row1['name'];

    $date1=date("Y/m/d");
    $dept_id = $_SESSION['dept_id'];
$query = "INSERT INTO request (`date`, `description`, `from`, `emp_id`, `to`)

    VALUES

('$date1','$_POST[description]','$dept_name','$emp_id','$_POST[to]')";
```

it works correctly.

Then the administrator choose the request by employee ID from comboBox when he press the accept button the data should updated

and this is its code

```
if(array_key_exists('accept', $_POST)) { 
   $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("employee_transfare", $conn);  
  $emp_id=$_POST['emp_id'];
  $dept_id = $_SESSION['dept_id'];
   $query="UPDATE employee SET dept_id='$dept_id' WHERE emp_id= $emp_id ";

  $n=mysql_query($query, $conn);

  if($n==0)
    echo "<h2>details already updated </h2>";
  else
    echo "<h2>details successfully updated</h2>";       
  mysql_close($conn);   
  }
else {
```

It always gives details already updated ...

How I can do it?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL-injection: you should look at MySQLi (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to make your code more secure. In the meantime, add die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); after your "details already updated" to see why the query is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You are not approaching things properly
mysql_query($query, $conn); will return a Boolean value (true or false).So your code is not working proplerly.

Try the in following way

```
$n=mysql_query($query, $conn);
 if (mysql_affected_rows()>0){
   echo "<h2>details successfully updated</h2>";       
 }else{
    echo "<h2>details already updated </h2>";
}

  mysql_close($conn);   
  }
```

Hope if you will solve your problem. TO know more how its work visit : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

on the otherhand, i would like to suggest you either use PDO or mysqli , you know mysql is deprecated.